# Should one put labels on Previous / Next buttons?

Tags: navigation, buttons, labels

We have several pages of case studies (about 10) and we want to put "Next" and "Previous" buttons at the bottom to go to the next / previous case studies.

What is the best practice... should we just keep them to "Next" / "Previous" or is it better to label them e.g. "Previous: [CASE STUDY BRAND 1]" / "Next: [CASE STUDY BRAND 2]" so that the user has an idea what's next and what was before?

Comment: I would imagine that previous/next is good enough (assuming you haven't left out details). Most users are aware of the previous thing they've read, and not knowing the next case study's title until "clicking next" is hardly a detriment. If you had a specific hypothesis with predicted outcomes you were trying to measure, then I might suggest a different approach.

Comment: Don't forget to add keyboard shortcuts for left and right to support experienced users.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on a couple of factors:

- Assuming the user lands on a study case only from within your website, you can omit the title in the "Previous" and eliminate the repetitive entities in the next, e.g "Next: Brand 2" instead of "Next: [CASE STUDY BRAND 2]"
- Assuming that you go social and there is a case that the user lands on the study case from other sources, different than your own website, e.g Facebook or Twitter, it will be relevant to show "Previous: Brand 1" and "Next: Brand 3" as she would have not gone through the linear path of viewing your studycases